# Languages with locale-specific functions

Tags: discussion

The only such language I can think of now is Excel. It has different function names in different language versions.

Some submissions can be made shorter by changing the language from the language default on this site, namely English.
This may also be used in obfuscation challenges (although in my opinion you should specify the locale version you're using).

**Is it fair to use the specific locale versions of the same programming language?**

*Note: It's not about locale-specific output [(like here)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209/what-about-locale-sensitive-output), but the function names being different in different locales*

Comment: Can you give an example of such a function? Also, I think [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/276/34718) may still apply.

Comment: Some examples (en-de): http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-german.html This site has also different translations.

Comment: Small Basic is another. There's a massive XML file for each locale, and it's theoretically possible to create a golfing language with little to no effort by changing the statements to single letters... Brb. :-)

Answer (score 12):

Sounds perfectly fair to me, just like using a certain dialect of a programming language or inventing your own.

Comment: Seems correct to me, but you might want to add that just like in those cases you should make which language you used clear in the header.