# `sort` alias for Powershell

Tags: discussion

[Source answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187449/80745)

### Intro

- Powershell introduced by Microsoft in 2006 for Windows OS.
- Since earlier versions, Powershell provides predefined aliases for commands. For example, alias `sort` for command `sort-object`.
- Microsoft has released Powershell for Linux in 2018 (Powershell 6.1+).
- Powershell 6.1+ for Linux contains predefined aliases, but the `sort` alias is not included in the standard package. Powershell 6.1+ for Windows still contains `sort` among the other aliases.

### Questions

1. Do you think it is possible to use `sort` in Powershell answers?
2. is it need additional comments in answers to use `sort`?
3. How have similar cases been solved for other languages?

Thanks

Comment: This is how Powershell 6.2.1 behaves in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS for clarity, not only for `sort`, but also for the `ls` and `man` aliases.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/567) and [this pull](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/786). Dennis, I think, made the profile modification from issue 567 so that TIO works for `sort` and the like.

Comment: [An example of it working on TIO (with its version table)](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NUx0THWMdIx1Czpji/qIRLpaC4DCibmZ9XkpiUk/r/PwA) along with [Dennis' pre-loaded aliases](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/blob/34eea9277eab04f4ee83f2fc55792995a37fdb9e/wrappers/powershell#L14)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes

This sounds perfectly fine to me. There are a couple similar questions. For example...

- [Languages with locale-specific functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11986/31716)
- [Are compiler-specific submissions allowed?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5851/are-compiler-specific-submissions-allowed)

And there are *plenty* of answers that work in Linux but not Windows, or vice-versa. In PPCG, a language is defined by its implementation, so as long as it works on one implementation (in this case, Windows Powershell 6.1), then it's a valid submission.

It would probably be best for you to mention if an answer is Windows specific. Either like this:

> ## Powershell, 1 bajillion bytes
>
> ```
> <some code>
> ```
>
> Doesn't work on Linux because it uses the `sort` alias.

Or

> ## Windows Powershell 6.1, 1 bajillion bytes:
>
> ```
> <some code>
> ```

The same idea applies if you wanted to use the Linux specific aliases.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

On PPCG, we define languages by their implementation/interpreter. So, as long as the `sort` alias exists in any one version of Powershell and an interpreter exists for that version, it's fair game.

The only requirement then is, when posting solutions that use `sort`, to include the version name/number with the language name.